# Getting notified when AngularJS app has loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS app that have some directives in it. The app loads some HTML from external HTML files.
The problem is that the controllers in the app communicate using events and the controllers of the HTML elements that are loaded from the external HTML files are initialized and starting to listen to events after other controllers had already started firing events.
It goes something like this:
index.html:

```
...
<body ng-controller="bodyController">
<ng-include src="page.html"></ng-include>
</body>
...
```

page.html:

```
<div ng-controller="divController"></div>
```

and the bodyController starts firing events before divController starts listening for them since the DIV from page.html is loaded after bodyController is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some luck listening for the $viewContentLoaded event from the controller:

```
    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
        // do what you need done on load complete
    });
```

It doesn't seem to pick up on whether the directives on the page have completed loading/rendering, but should cover the other cases